# If you choose to roll for starting gold for your class, do you get starting equipment from your background as well?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, equipment, background, wealth

Say you choose to roll for starting gold for your class (and then buy equipment).

Do you still get the starting equipment from your background (but not from your class)?
Or do you not get any starting equipment at all, from either your class or your background?

Is it just up to the DM?

Answer (score 29):

### You don't get any starting equipment at all - just the gold

The ["Starting Equipment"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#StartingEquipment) section at the start of Chapter 5: Equipment states (PHB, p. 143):

> When you create your character, you receive equipment based on a combination of your class and background. Alternatively, you can start with a number of gold pieces based on your class and spend them on items from the lists in this chapter. See the Starting Wealth by Class table to determine how much gold you have to spend.

So by the rules, if you choose to buy your equipment, you don't get any equipment from your class or background. Ask your DM, however, since many houserule different starting equipment, especially above level 1.